# How to find distance s1?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Here is a screenshot of a problem from my textbook

[image]

My book says

$$S₁= 2t (\tan(\theta_{2})\cos(\theta_{1}))$$

I know the distance for $\overline{AC}$ is

$$2t (\tan(\theta_{2})) $$

but where did $\cos(\theta_1) $  come from?

How is  $S_{1}=$ distance between $\overline{AC}$ and $(\cos(\theta_{1}))$?

Comment: Where else is $\theta_1$?

Comment: theta 1 is the angle between the ray touching point A and theta 1. How did the book relate this to S1? Basically What geometrical theorem did they use?

Comment: Draw distance $S_1$ starting from $C$. It will form a right triangle with hypotenuse $AC$, where the angle opposite to $S_1$ is $\theta_1$

Comment: There seem to be some missing assumptions here. $AB = BC$? $AD\perp AB$? The extension of $AD$ bisects the angle?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please see the diagram.

From $\triangle ADB$, we can calculate that $DB = t\tan\theta_2$. Now $AC = 2DB = 2t\tan\theta_2$.

Denote point $X$ such that $\triangle AXC$ is a right triangle, with the right angle being at $X$. $\angle ACX = \theta_1$, by the theorem of corresponding angles. Since $AC$ is the hypotenuse of this triangle, and $CX$ is the adjacent side to the angle $ACX$, $s_1 = AC\cos\theta_1 = 2t\tan\theta_2\cos\theta_1$, as required.

Just to add on, the comment on the question bringing up unstated assumptions is a very fair one. But this problem seems to be one on the classical theory of refraction and partial/total internal reflection in the topic of optics (in physics), so the ray diagram and its inherent assumptions are fairly obvious. Nevertheless, it would be good for the asker to confirm this.

Comment: Yes it is related to a refraction problem. Instead of using a theorem, is there a way I could prove <ACX= theta_1 easily?

Comment: @Anoy7sy Corresponding angles is a very basic geometric fact. More just a property than a fancy-pantsy theorem. Look it up.